# Trying to create a dynamic list item. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I have a couple of list items, on the left side and aligned vertically. I'm trying to make so that the container on the right side, which is empty, will populate with information from the url for that list item's specific id. I was able to create a jQuery function using load() and it allowed me to click within the list item and data was populated in the right container, but it's only the data for the smallest id. If I click the other list items, the data in the right container doesn't change. Currently, I added this line of code,

```
var strReqUrl = $(this).attr('href'); 
alert(strReqUrl);
```

to see if an alert would display the link it's supposed to be using. When I click within the list item, the alert says "Undefined".  :(

I tried adding a link within the list item, and it works. The correct data is shown, however, I leave my current page every time to see it and it doesn't populate in the container on the right at all, which is now on the previous page.

Is there anyway to get the proper id assigned to the proper list item?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("li").click(function(){
          var strReqUrl = $(this).attr('href');
          alert(strReqUrl);             
    //$("#divId").load("pm_message.php?u=<?php echo $log_username; ?>&pmid=<?php echo $pmid; ?> #pm_post");
       });
    });
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper"> <!--Left and Right container wrapper-->
    <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <!--left container-->
      <div class="top">
        <input type="text" />
        <a href="javascript:;" class="search"></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="people">
        <a href="pm_message.php?u=<?php echo $log_username; ?>&pmid=<?php echo $pmid; ?>"><?php echo $people; ?></a> <!--generates list of people-->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right" id="right">
      <!--Right container-->
      <div class="top"><span class="name"></span></div>
      <div id="divId"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And script:

```
//DB connection
    //Collecting data from db
    //Variable $people collects data for the people listed in the left container
    $people = '
                <li class="person">
                  <a id="a" href="pm_message.php?u='.$log_username.'&pmid='.$pmid.'"><span class="name">'.$sender.'</span></a>
                            <!--<span class="name">'.$sender.'</span>-->
                            <span class="time">'.$time.'</span>
                            <span class="preview">'.$message.'</span>
                </li>';
```

Comment: Your li didn't have a href attribute. Use $('li > a').click(...)

Answer (score 0):

When you assign event handlers, **li** is not already in the document. You need to use delegated handling. And the **href** attribute you are looking for is not there. Try this:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var strReqUrl = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    alert(strReqUrl);
});
```

See more - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: it's already, server-side generated. your code will not work here, li didn't have a href attribute

Comment: Thanks for you help. For some reason nothing is happening. I'll keep playing with it.